# Java: Figuring out if a phone number (string) is a palindrome

Tags: java, palindrome

I need to find out if a phone number is a palindrome. I have this code:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String j)
{
  boolean pali;
  String rev = "";
  String reverse = new StringBuffer(j).reverse().toString();
  j.toString();
  if (j.equals(reverse))
     pali = false;
  else if (!j.equals(reverse))
     pali = true;
  return pali;
}
```

This code is giving me this error: The local variable may not have been initialized. How can I fix this?

Comment: This question is mis-titled

Comment: Read this "Definite Assignment": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By initializing the local variable:

```
boolean pali = false; // Default value before you know it is a palindrome
```

Comment: Thank you! I always forget to do that

Comment: Better yet, eliminate `pali` and `return j.equals(reverse);`